# SUM numbers with multiple criteria as word in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to SUM cells range in column betwen two diffrent value as word?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the desire output as sample?

Comment: @Rocky desired output is all colored cells in D column.

Comment: @SmekeriBezPrezimena -  ...so a single total of all coloured cells in that column?  If it's actually formatted like that, it's probably easier to look for the colours instead of the words. (If that's not what you're trying to do, it would be helpful if you added a [mcve] to your question.)

Comment: @ashleedawg In reality, the cells are not colored, it's just an example for a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

In your case a helper column will come in handy:

[image]

Array Formula in `E2`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),INDEX(C2:$C$33,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(C2:$C$33),0)),"Value 2")
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down...

Formula in `D33`:

```
=SUMIF(E2:E32,"Value 2",D2:D32)
```